# How do I calculate values extracted from a file using grep and use those value to calculate

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, grep

I need to calculate some values in a file (Case1.log) which contains,

```
Fault Classes                                                                              #faults
                                                                                           (total)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  --------------
  FU (full)                                                                                 3186
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------  --------------
  DS (det_simulation)                                                                   1625 (51.00%)
  DI (det_implication)                                                                   393 (12.34%)
  PU (posdet_untestable)                                                                 123 ( 1.32%)
  PT (posdet_testable)                                                                   420 ( 2.43%)
  UU (unused)                                                                            210 ( 6.59%)
  TI (tied)                                                                               52 ( 1.63%)
  BL (blocked)                                                                             4 ( 0.13%)
  RE (redundant)                                                                           9 ( 0.28%)
  AU (atpg_untestable)                                                                   893 (28.03%)
```

I have extracted the values from the above file using bash scripting as below,

```
#! /bin/bash
DS=$(grep DS $1 | awk -F " " '{print $3" "}')
echo "DS=$DS"
DI=$(grep DI $1 | awk -F " " '{print $3" "}')
echo "DI=$DI"
UU=$(grep UU $1 | awk -F " " '{print $3" "}')
echo "UU=$UU"
TI=$(grep TI $1 | awk -F " " '{print $3" "}')
echo "TI=$TI"
BL=$(grep BL $1 | awk -F " " '{print $3" "}')
echo "BL=$BL"
RE=$(grep RE $1 | awk -F " " '{print $3" "}')
echo "RE=$RE"
PU=$(grep PU $1 | awk -F " " '{print $3" "}')
echo "PU=$PU"
PT=$(grep PT $1 | awk -F " " '{print $3" "}')
echo "PT=$PT"
FU=$(grep FU $1 | awk -F " " '{print $3" "}')
echo "FU=$FU"
```

Now I need to use the extracted values to calculate an equation,

```
NU = expr $DS + $DI + $PT + $PU 
DE = expr $FU - $UU - $TI - $BL - $RE | bc -l

Result = expr $NU / $DE \*100
echo $Result
```

Upon running the script

```
bash Script.sh Case1.log
```

$NU, $DE & $ Result are showing an Error text as

```
DS=1625
DI=393
UU=210
TI=52
BL=4
RE=9
PU=123
PT=420
FU=3186
2561
2911
expr: missing operand
Try 'expr --help' for more information.
/
expr: syntax error: unexpected argument ‘case1.log’
```

Comment: Why don't you do it entirely with awk?

Comment: Can you help me with the command

Comment: `grep | awk` is (almost) always wrong.  Parsing an input file multiple times with `awk` to extract fields is (almost) always wrong.  You do want to do the entire thing in awk, so parsing the fields into the shell is not what you want, but for the sake of demonstration you can do that with : `sort input | awk '$1 ~ /[A-Z]{2}/{printf "%d ", $3 ? $3 : 0}' | { read AU BL DI DS FU PT PU RE TI UU; echo $UU; }` (You cannot use `expr` for anything but integer arithmetic, so I'm using `echo` to demonstrate how to reference the variables, since they will not be valid after the `}`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing it entirely with awk:

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S awk -f

# Parse records containing key of two uppercase letters
$1 ~ /[A-Z]{2}/ {
  # Populate associative array with captured key and value
  a[$1] = $3

  # For debug purpose
  printf("%s = %s\n", $1, $3)
}

END {
  # Now that all values have been captured into the associative array,
  # perform computations
  NU = a["DS"] + a["DI"] + a["PT"] + a["PU"]
  DE = a["FU"] - a["UU"] - a["TI"] - a["BL"] - a["RE"]
  result = 100 * NU / DE
  printf("\nNU = %d\nDE = %d\n", NU, DE)
  printf("100 * NU / DE = %f\n", result)
}
```

Save awk script above for example as `nuderatio`, and
make it executable `chmod +x nuderatio`

and run it

```sh
./nuderatio Case1.log
```

Output it get from your sample `Case1.log`:

```
FU = 3186
DS = 1625
DI = 393
PU = 123
PT = 420
UU = 210
TI = 52
BL = 4
RE = 9
AU = 893

NU = 2561
DE = 2911
100 * NU / DE = 87.976640
```

And same entirely in Bash:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A a

while read -r k _ v _ || [[ $k ]]; do
  [[ "$k" =~ [A-Z]{2} ]] || continue
  a[$k]="$v"
  printf '%s = %s\n' "$k" "$v"
done < "$1"

NU=$((a["DS"] + a["DI"] + a["PT"] + a["PU"]))
DE=$((a["FU"] - a["UU"] - a["TI"] - a["BL"] - a["RE"]))

# Precision decimals
p=8

r=$((10**p * 100 * NU / DE))

result="${r:0:$((${#r} - p))}.${r: -$p}"

printf '\nNU = %d\nDE = %d\n' $NU $DE
LC_ALL=C printf '100 * NU / DE = %f\n' "$result"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two simple ways to do calculations in UNIX/Linux shells: `$((...))` and `awk`.

`$((...))` is very simple:

```
Prompt> echo $((1+2*3))
7
```

However, it only covers integer calculation:

```
Prompt> echo $((3/5))
0
```

So, once floating point arithmetic is involved, it's advised to use another system, like `awk`:

```
Prompt> awk '{print 3/5}'
0.6
```

Oh, as far as percentages are concerned: integer arithmetic has a tiny drawback as you can see (how much percent is 3/5):

```
Prompt> echo $((100 * 3 / 5))
60

Prompt> echo $((3 / 5 * 100))
0
```

(first, 3/5 gets calculated, being zero, ...)